# AS3 - Adding new instances of a Class with Spacebar

Tags: actionscript-3, class, addchild

I have 2 classes, Main and Rocket, and I am trying to create a new instance of Rocket every time I hit the space bar. Here is what I have right now:

```
Main.as:

package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{       
    // player
    private var _player:MovieClip;

    // player settings
    private var _maxSpeed:Number = 5;
    private var _rotationSpeed:Number = 5;
    private var _thrust:Number = 0.5;
    private var _decay:Number = .97;        

    private var _currentSpeed:Number = 0;
    private var _speedX:Number = 0;
    private var _speedY:Number = 0;

    // keyboard flags
    private var _movingUp:Boolean = false;
    private var _movingLeft:Boolean = false;
    private var _movingRight:Boolean = false;
    private var _pressingSpace:Boolean = false;

    private var rocket:Rocket = new Rocket();
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function Main() 
    {

        createPlayer();

        // add listeners
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);           
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myOnPress); // ANY KEY



        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, myOnRelease);      // ANY KEY  
    }

    /**
     * Creates player
     */
    private function createPlayer():void
    {
        _player = new Player();
        _player.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        _player.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        stage.addChild(_player);


    }

    /**
     * EnterFrame Handlers
     */
    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        // Rotate right or left
        if (_movingRight)
        {
            _player.rotation += _rotationSpeed;
        }

        if (_pressingSpace)
        {
            rocket.x = _player.x;
            addChild(rocket);

        }

        if (_movingLeft)
        {
            _player.rotation -= _rotationSpeed;
        }
        if (_movingUp)
        {


            trace(("Speed var before executing x"), + _speedX,  ("Speed var before executing y"), + _speedY);

            _speedX += _thrust * Math.sin(_player.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)); // as closer you are to 90 or -90 degrees in radians(+90* is 1 radian) the faster you accelarte to x or -x
            _speedY += _thrust * Math.cos(_player.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)); //as closer you are to 0 or 180 degrees in radians(+90* is 1 radian) the faster you accelarte to y

            trace(("the rad sin: ") + Math.sin(_player.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
            trace(_player.rotation);    
            trace(("Speed var x"), + _speedX,  ("Speed var y"), + _speedY);
            trace(("cos rad y ") + Math.cos(_player.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
            trace("current speed" + _currentSpeed);
        } 
        else{
            // Deccelerate when Up Arrow key is released
            // if you wanna stop right now: _speedX = 0;
            // if you wanna stop right now: _speedY = 0;
            _speedX *= _decay;
            _speedY *= _decay;
        }

        // Maintain speed limit
        _currentSpeed = Math.sqrt((_speedX * _speedX) + (_speedY * _speedY)); // using this method in order to turn negative (if there are) numbers into positive, then add them together to find combined speed.

        if (_currentSpeed > _maxSpeed) // if combined speed (x + y) exceeds max speed (5), divide max speed by current speed, which always will return a number below 1. then multiply that number to both y and x speed to slow down
        {
            _speedX *= _maxSpeed/_currentSpeed; // 
            _speedY *= _maxSpeed/_currentSpeed; // 
        }

        // Move _player based on calculations above
        _player.y -= _speedY; // What's y worth right now + add the speed of y
        _player.x += _speedX; // What's x worth right now + add the speed of x

    }

    /**
     * Key Press Handlers
     */
    public function myOnPress(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        switch( event.keyCode )
        {
            case Keyboard.UP:
                _movingUp = true;
                break;

            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                _movingLeft = true;
                break;

            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                _movingRight = true;
                break;

            case Keyboard.SPACE:
                _pressingSpace = true;
                break;  
        }
    }

    /**
     * Key Release Handlers
     */
    public function myOnRelease(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        switch( event.keyCode )
        {
            case Keyboard.UP:
                _movingUp = false;
                break;

            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                _movingLeft = false;
                break;

            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                _movingRight = false;
                break;

            case Keyboard.SPACE:
                _pressingSpace = false;
                break;  
        }
    }

 }
```

### }

```
       Rocket.as:
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Rocket extends Sprite
    {

        [Embed(source = "red_dot.gif")] public static var pictureClass:Class;      // save image to class

        private var myBitmap:Bitmap = new pictureClass; // create bitmap data


        public function Rocket() 
        {
            addChild(myBitmap); // add the bitmap
        }

    }

}
```

So right now, when I press the space bar the class with the bitmap is added to the screen with addChild, and the x of that image is the same as player's x(I have a player that can move). Next time I click the spacebar(without releasing space), It just follows me around to wherever I go with my player. what I want to do is, to add a new image rocket every time I click the space bar to wherever my player's x is. Btw later on I wanna be able to manipulate each of these newly created images, so put it also into consideration please.
Thank you.

Comment: how are you updating the value for the boolean `_pressingSpace`. Can you show some code for that too? Also you are right now only creating one instance of Rocket in your Main class. Don't you want a new instance every time?

Comment: I've just updated the entire code. Yes, I would like a new instance every time (Its supposed to shoot from the circle but ill do it),but i am not sure how to generate instance every single time (I'd like later on to delete it whenever it hits an object and so on.)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You instantiate with the `new` keyword.  Currently, at the top of your code you create a class level var called `rocket` and instantiate a `Rocket` in the same line.  So only one rocket is ever being created.   You you use `addChild`, it's just re-adding the same item over and over (which essentially has no noticeable effect).

What you need to do, is create an Array/Vector to store all your rockets, and instantiate when the space bar is pressed (or, if you want to limit how often a rocket can be created, in your enter frame handler).

First, replace your class level `rocket` var with a Vector to store all rockets:

```
private var rockets:Vector.<Rocket> = new Vector.<Rocket>();
//vectors and the same as arrays, only all members have to be of the specified class (or inherit from it)
```

This way, you have an easy/speedy way to iterate over all your rockets.

Then, when you hit space bar, create a `new` rocket and add it to the screen and array/vector

```
    case Keyboard.SPACE:
        _pressingSpace = true;
        var rocket:Rocket = new Rocket();
        rocket.x = player.x;
        addChild(rocket);
        rockets.push(rocket);
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a time based approach to limit how often a rocket can be shot/spawned.  instead of the code above, you would do this in the enter frame handler.

First though, create a class level var to hold the next time a rocket is allowed to fire:

```
private var rocketTime:int;
```

Then, modify your enter frame handler like so:

```
    if (_pressingSpace)
    {
        if(flash.utils.getTimer() >= rocketTime){
            var rocket:Rocket = new Rocket();
            rockets.push(rocket);
            rocket.x = player.x;
            addChild(rocket);
            rocketTime = flash.utils.getTimer() + 500; //say you want to wait at least half a second before spawning a new rocket.
        }
    }
```

---

At some point, you'll have to check if the rocket is colliding with something.
You'll want to do that in an enter frame handler.  If you determine it is colliding, you'll need to remove the rocket.

Let's assume you have an Array/Vector of enemies called `enemies`.  In your enter frame handler, you'd want something along these lines:

```
//loop backwards through your rockets array
for(var i:int=rockets.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
    //you'll want to to move your rockets, however you do that
    rockets[i].y -= 5; 

    //next, check if this rocket collides with any enemies
    for(var j:int = enemies.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
        if(rockets[i].hitTestObject(enemies[j])){
            //yes, it collides! remove the rocket and the enemy
            removeChild(enemies[j]);
            removeChild(rockets[i]);

            enemies.splice(j,1); //take it out of the array
            rockets.splice(i,1);

            //when you splice an array, you shift all the indexes
                //this is why you need to iterate backwards instead of forwards        
            //because we've spliced, you can no longer use rockets[i] or enemies[j] after this point in the loops
                //they will either be null, refer to different items than they did before you spliced
            break; //don't keep checking enemies in this for loop as we've removed the rocket
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good mate, just 1 more question: Can I actually remove one or more values from that vector, in a way that it will also delete the image on the screen that is related to that stored space in the vector?

Comment: The bottom most part of my answer addresses that.  You use the `splice` on an array/vector to remove 1 or more items.  You use removeChild to remove it from the screen.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Good answer Sir. +1 :)